# which cocos2d project to use for android?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

We are building a game with sns features.
We are planning to use native framework(e.g. UIKit for iOS) for sns features.

With that in mind,

which one would be better?

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/ or http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/

Answer (score 1):

By which definition of "better" are we supposed to decide what is "better" for you?

I'm answering this question by saying that you should try out both, then go with the engine that you feel more productive with. Make the quickest prototype possible using the minimum features you require. In your case that might be displaying a native UI view inside a cocos2d OpenGL view.

For more information about what really matters when selecting an engines read my ["game engine picker guide"](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/05/the-game-engine-dating-guide-how-to-find-the-right-engine-for-your-game/).

Answer (score 1):

I think might be cocos2d-x. I did compare those two, basically, the android one is almost dead and there is no update any more. and the support and tutorials is pool.

But cocos2d-x will be difficult when you try to integrated with the SDK features as you need to go through jni. However, there are plenty of tutorials online to show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted cocos2d-x in  windows environment using eclipse and eventually decided against it because it lacks debugging support and proper IDE integration, which is very good in Java/Android/eclipse/ADT. The only way I would recommend cocos2d-x is if you are developing for IOS and then porting to Android but I don't know about UIKit and SNS.